# How to make a multi-tab pop up with css

Tags: javascript, css, tabs, popup

I have been trying to work my way around the following codes

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang ="en">
<head>
<style type="text/css">
a{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#333;
 }
#pop{
 width:557px;
 height:400px;
 background:#333;
 left: 30%;
 margin-top:80px;
 z-index:999999;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000;
 border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 -o-border-radius: 5px;
}
#pop2{
 width:557px;
 height:400px;
 background:#333;
 left: 30%;
 margin-top:80px;
 z-index:999999;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000;
 border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 -o-border-radius: 5px;
}

.content {
 width:100%;
 background: #fff;
 color:#666;
 width:500px;
 height: 300px;
 overflow-y:scroll;
 margin:auto;
 padding:10px;
 text-align:justify;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #333 inset;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #333 inset;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #333 inset;
}

#pop:target{
 height:30px;
 width:250px;
 overflow:hidden;
 position:fixed;
 bottom:0;
 left:236px;
}
#pop2:target{
 height:30px;
 width:250px;
 overflow:hidden;
 position:fixed;
 bottom:0;
 left:236px;
}
</style>
</head>

<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('pop').style.display='block';">
    CLICK HERE
</a>  
 
<div id="pop" style="display:none;">
<div class="buttons-bar">
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Header
<a href="" onclick="document.getElementById('pop').style.display='none'">X</a>
<a href="#">></a>
<a href="#pop" >-</a>
</div>
<div class="content">
The standard Lorem Ipsum passage, used since the 1500s
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

</div>
</div> 
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('pop2').style.display='block';">
    CLICK HERE
</a>  
 
<div id="pop" style="display:none;">
<div class="buttons-bar">
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Header
<a href="" onclick="document.getElementById('pop2').style.display='none'">X</a>
<a href="#">></a>
<a href="#pop2" >-</a>
</div>
<div class="content">
The standard Lorem Ipsum passage, used since the 1500s
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

</div>
</div> 
</html>
```

But the problem here is, im using ":target" pseudo class and so only one tab can be opened, when the pop-up is minimized, and the other pop-up is opened and minimized, the first one just pops open, but id like to have multiple tabs. Any ideas as to how i'd go around it?, any ideas are welcome, even javascript. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, here's something that I cooked up.

I made it easily expandable, all you have to do is copy the HTML for another tab.  If this wasn't what you were looking for, I can modify it.

Edit: Fixed code so minimized pop ups will minimize others then maximize

http://jsfiddle.net/weissman258/cd866j6h/4/

```js
function expand_collapse(elem) {
    var top_div = elem.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
    if (top_div.classList.contains("maximized")) {
        elem.innerHTML = "&#9650;";
        top_div.classList.toggle("minimized", true);
        top_div.classList.toggle("maximized", false);
    } else {
        var popouts = document.getElementsByClassName("pop_out");
        for(var i=0;i<popouts.length;i++) {
            popouts[i].classList.toggle("minimized", true);
            popouts[i].classList.toggle("maximized", false);
            popouts[i].getElementsByClassName("expand_collapse")[0].innerHTML = "&#9650;";
        }
    elem.innerHTML = "&#9660;";
    top_div.classList.toggle("maximized", true);
    top_div.classList.toggle("minimized", false);
    }
}

function close_pop(elem) {
    elem.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.display = 'none';
}
```

```css
.pop_out {
  background: #333;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000;
}
.pop_content {
  background: white;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 2px;
}
.minimized {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 250px;
  height: 60px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.maximized {
  top: 0;
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  /* Whatever styling you want when maximized, as long as you add the same styling to minimized class to change it back */
}
.close_pop {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.close_pop:hover {
  color: red;
}
.expand_collapse {
  margin-right: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.expand_collapse:hover {
  color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div style="position:fixed;bottom:-4px;">
  <div class="pop_out minimized">
    <div style="padding:2px;position:relative;"> <span style="margin-left:10px;">Tab 1</span>
      <span style="position:absolute;right:15px;">
     <span class="expand_collapse" onclick="expand_collapse(this);">&#9650;</span>
      <span class="close_pop" onclick="close_pop(this);">X</span></span>
    </div>
    <div class="pop_content">The standard Lorem Ipsum passage, used since the 1500s "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
      nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est
      laborum.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="pop_out minimized">
    <div style="padding:2px;position:relative;"> <span style="margin-left:10px;">Tab 2</span>
      <span style="position:absolute;right:15px;">
     <span class="expand_collapse" onclick="expand_collapse(this);">&#9650;</span>
      <span class="close_pop" onclick="close_pop(this);">X</span></span>
    </div>
    <div class="pop_content">The standard Lorem Ipsum passage, used since the 1500s "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
      nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est
      laborum.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thats good, i see you improved it so that only one tab can be opened at a time, thats a good idea, but how about the first link that says "click here to open"? and the code can only close not minimize. Its quite challenging and i was also thinking of something like this $('.class1').toggleClass('.class2') .

Comment: @John What do you mean it can only close not minimize?  Have you clicked the triangle

Comment: @Weiss, sorry what i meant was that if the maximize button(triangle) was clicked on the minimized tab, it wouldnt replace the maximized tab, the previous would have to be closed first, i might just play around with this code and use it like this, Thanks but if you have other ideas please share. :)

Comment: @John Okay, I see what you mean.  You could make it so anytime the maximize button is clicked, it applies the minimized class to all the elements with the pop_out class, except for the one being clicked.

Comment: yes that worked awesome, i've been fiddling with it but i have been unable to create a hyperlink to call the class in the first place, i mean i dont wanna start the page with the minimized tab, a hyperlink should open the tab initially, before it gets minimized, kindly show me this so i may proceed. Thanks a lot :).

Answer (score 0):

Like This...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.show-popup').on('click', function() {
    $('.popup').fadeIn();
  });
  $('.close_pop').on('click', function() {
    $('.popup').fadeOut();
  });
});

var max = true;

function expand_collapse(elem) {
  var top_div = elem.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
  if (max === false) {
    elem.innerHTML = "&#9660;";
    top_div.classList.toggle("minimized", false);
    top_div.classList.toggle("maximized", true);
    max = true;
  } else if (top_div.classList.contains("maximized")) {
    elem.innerHTML = "&#9650;";
    top_div.classList.toggle("minimized", true);
    top_div.classList.toggle("maximized", false);
    max = false
  }
}

function close_pop(elem) {
  var top_div = elem.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
  top_div.style.display = 'none';
  if (top_div.classList.contains("maximized")) {
    max = false;
  }
};
```

```css
.popup {
  display: none;
}
.pop_out {
  background: #333;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000;
}
.minimized {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 250px;
  height: 60px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.maximized {
  top: 0;
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  /* Whatever styling you want when maximized, as long as you add the same styling to minimized class to change it back */
}
.close_pop {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
}
.close_pop:hover {
  color: red;
}
.expand_collapse {
  margin-right: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  height: 3px;
}
.expand_collapse:hover {
  color: #ccc;
}
a {
  position: fixed;
  top: 150;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="show-popup" href="#">CLICK HERE</a>
<!--Right Here -->
<div class="popup" style="position:fixed;bottom:0px;">
  <div class="pop_out maximized">
    <div style="padding:2px;position:relative;"> <span style="margin-left:10px;">Tab 1</span>
      <span style="position:absolute;right:15px;">
     <span class="expand_collapse" onclick="expand_collapse(this);">&#9660;</span>
      <span class="close_pop">&times</span></span>
    </div>
    <div style="background:white;font-size:15px;padding:2px;">The standard Lorem Ipsum passage, used since the 1500s "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
      nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est
      laborum.
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Now i'm able to open from a link thanks a lot.

Comment: Looks good, as long as you don't want to be able to open each pop out individually - that would take some reworking.  I would love to see the final product implemented.  Also, remember to accept my answer.

Comment: I have been trying to vote your answer but i need 15 reps, will do asap.